# php preg_match decimal with a precision of 2

Tags: php

I need to check amount make sure it's correct like

```
10995.25 //true
0.21 //true
2.30 //true
100.00 //true

100 //false
15.2 //false
214.353 //false
```

anyone know how to use PHP `preg_match` expression to achieve this

Comment: Why to use preg_match only as it is used for string matching?

Comment: Have you tried anything with `preg_match`? Is this one large string or multiple individual inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match` is basically used for pattern matching.

You can acheive this like below but without preg_match function:

```
<?php
$str = "10995.25";
echo $total_decimals = strlen(substr(strrchr($str, "."), 1));
// Output will be 2

if($total_decimals == 2){
     echo "True";
} else {
     echo "False";
}
// Output will be True here for 10995.25 and False for 100 or 15.2
?>
```

Comment: Yes if decimal is not 2 then false

Comment: After finding decimal he can easily do that by comparing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
preg_match('~(\d+)\.([\d]{2})~',$input,$match);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
if (preg_match('/^\d+\.\d{2}$/', $str)) {

    // valid string 
}
```

Please note this would not match something like .34 if you need to match that as well then replace + with *